# google-api-ruby-client 0.9 tokeninfo lacks an example

Tags: ruby, google-api-client, google-api-ruby-client

I thought that using Google's official ruby client API would be the easiest way to validate an access_token that hits my backend server.
Not really.
Version 0.9 has not a simple sample of validating an access token and API docs doesn't help neither.

I have got this far:

```
require 'google/apis/oauth2_v2'
oauth = Google::Apis::Oauth2V2::Oauth2Service.new
oauth.tokeninfo({access_token: 'aaaaaaaa...'})
=> Google::Apis::ClientError: Invalid request
```

docs on `google-api-client-0.9.4/generated/google/apis/oauth2_v2/service.rb` say that tokeninfo method raises:

```
[Google::Apis::ServerError] An error occurred on the server and the request can be retried
[Google::Apis::ClientError] The request is invalid and should not be retried without modification
[Google::Apis::AuthorizationError] Authorization is required
```

How can I tell that the token is invalid ?!?

Can you guys share some examples ?